# Set a different var value if the "for" loop returns an error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a script that checks another spreadsheet for the name of a customer and returns the associated customer's code. It works great as long as the customer name is in the "CustomerCodes" sheet that it references. If the customer name does not exist there, I would like it to set the variable value "customerCode" to "No match found." Right now it just throws an error and  won't run the script any further. Here is the code:

```js
var customerName = sheet.getRange('I2').getValue();
  
  var ccsheet = ss.getSheetByName("CustomerCodes");
  var lastRow = ccsheet.getLastRow();
  
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  
  var lookUp = ccsheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 3).getValues();
  
  for (nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {
    if (lookUp[nn][0] == customerName) {break}
  }

  //This is where I am having the trouble 
  var customerCode = lookUp[nn][1];
  
  Logger.log("customerCode: " + customerCode);
```

So, if the "for" loop does find a match, it set the "customerCode" variable to that match. If it doesn't find a match, I would like it to set the "customerCode" variable to "No match found" so the user knows why the customer's code has not been returned.  The value of the variable "customerCode" is returned to the user later in the function.

I don't understand error handling very well as I am really new to all this, and I couldn't find any google apps script documentation that explained it well. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error I am getting is: "TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined (line 32,...). Line 32 is where I put the //This is where I'm having the trouble.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try your solution yet, but it looks like it will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For info, there are actually many ways to get the result you want... A more straightforward and readable way would be as follows :

```
var customerCode = 'no customer with this ID found in the list';
for (var nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {
    if (lookUp[nn][0] == customerName) {
        customerCode = lookUp[nn][1];
        break;
    }
}
```

which returns of course the very same result but avoids using the short form `IF THEN ELSE` statement (aka ternary operator) used above.

Comment: Thank you. That does seem like a more simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

So add code to see if you have a match. Other option is to check to see if the variable nn is less than the length

```
var matchIndex = -1;
for (var nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {
    if (lookUp[nn][0] == customerName) {
        matchIndex=nn;
        break;
    }
}

//This is where I am having the trouble 
var customerCode = matchIndex===-1 ? "Not found" : lookUp[matchIndex][1];
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Beautiful! What is a term that would describe this line so I can learn more about it?  var customerCode = matchIndex===-1 ? "Not found" : lookUp[matchIndex][1];

Comment: Perfect. I will look up information on ternary operators and learn how to use them. Thank you for pointing me to the right reference materials, too.